# Laravel unit testing same function twice and different output

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-5, integration-testing

I'm a bit new to Laravel unit testing. I need to get different outputs by calling same repo function for the unit testing.

So far my test is like this:

```
public function testReportOffdayWorked()
{
    $input = [
        'from_date' => '2016/01/01',
        'to_date' => '2016/01/03',
    ];

    $webServiceRepositoryMock = Mockery::mock('App\Repositories\WebServiceRepository');
    $webServiceRepositoryMock->shouldReceive('callGet')->twice()->andReturn($this->issues);
    $this->app->instance('App\Repositories\WebServiceRepository', $webServiceRepositoryMock);

    $this->call('post', '/reporting/portal/report-offdays', $input);
    $this->assertResponseOk();
    $this->assertTrue($this->response->original->getName() == "Reporting::report_offday_worked");
}
```

I would like to get two different outputs for `callGet` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up a sequence of return values or closures for `callGet()`.

> `andReturn(value1, value2, ...)`
>
> Sets up a sequence of return values or closures. For example, the first call will return value1 and the second value2. Note that all subsequent calls to a mocked method will always return the final value (or the only value) given to this declaration.
>
> — [docs.mockery](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/expectations.html)

The following shows how to do it in PHPUnit mocks and mockery.

```
<?php

class The {
    public function answer() { }
}

class MockingTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testMockConsecutiveCalls()
    {
        $mock = $this->getMock('The');
        $mock->expects($this->exactly(2))
             ->method('answer')
             ->will($this->onConsecutiveCalls(4, 2));

        $this->assertSame(4, $mock->answer());
        $this->assertSame(2, $mock->answer());
    }

    public function testMockeryConsecutiveCalls()
    {
        $mock = Mockery::mock('The');
        $mock->shouldReceive('answer')->andReturn(4, 2);

        $this->assertSame(4, $mock->answer());
        $this->assertSame(2, $mock->answer());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using PHPUnit mocking framework?

```
$mock = $this->getMock('ClassName');  

$mock->expects($this->at(0))
     ->method('getInt')
     ->will($this->returnValue('one'));

$mock->expects($this->at(1))
     ->method('getInt')
     ->will($this->returnValue('two'));

echo $mock->getInt(); //will return one
echo $mock->getInt(); //will return two
```

Comment: Exactly i want somthing like this with laravel Mock object. Anyway thanks for your answer :)